# How to get EditText value placed in another View

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have to make n number of edittexts as per data rows in the database. I added them in `LinearLayout` like:

```
for(Some Condition)
{
    EditText et = new EditText (this);
    et.setValue(SomeVal);
   li.addView(et);
}
```

And then, i added the LinearLayout to ScrollView which i'm using as view in AlertDialog.

Do i need to assign id to each EditText, and how can i later access the values of each EditText.

Comment: This is what RecyclerView is for, and you should be using that.

Comment: Yes, I would recommend using RecyclerView too

Answer (score 1):

I love to tackle this from another side.

Take the LinearLayout and search inside on the children one by one.

For example:

```
      String a;
      for (int i = 0; i< linearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
          a = ((EditText) linearLayout.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString();
          Log.i("go", "TextView text is:" + a);
      }
```

In your case change linearLayout to li.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create Views like this. Use a custom Adapter and a ListView or RecyclerView: https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial

You'll be able to reference each item by its position in the backing array.

Answer (score 0):

To access these Edittexts later, add them in some collection and then access through position:

```
Arraylist<EditText> edittexts = new Arraylist()

for(Some Condition) {
     EditText et = new EditText (this);
     et.setValue(SomeVal);
     li.addView(et);
     edittexts.add(et);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna stick to this way you can create a `HashMap`

```
HashMap<Integer/*EditText Id*/,EditText> myEditTexts = new HashMap<>();
```

Then in your code

```
for(Some Condition)
{
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
    et.setValue(SomeVal);
    /*Add This*/
    myEditTexts.put(intId,et);
    li.addView(et);
}
```

Then you can call it

```
myEditTexts.get(Id);
```

OR you can use a `RecyclerView` with `EditTexts` and reach it by position (If you don't know how, you can ask me for the way if you wanted this option)

Answer (score 0):

If you have reference variable of `LinearLayout` in which you are adding values, then you can get all its child views and access their data using below code. You won't need to assign ids to EditText's while adding them.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ll_main.getChildCount(); i++) {
    EditText child = (EditText)ll_main.getChildAt(i);
    child.getText(); 
}
```

Make sure your layout has only EditTexts in it or you would need to check object before casting to EditText.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Add Dynamic Edit Text:-

```
EditText et;
List<EditText> edtList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll);
        // add edittext
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            et = new EditText(this);
            edtList.add(et);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            et.setLayoutParams(p);
            et.setText("Text");
            et.setId(j);
            ll.addView(et);
        }
```

Retrieve Edit text:-

```
int id[]=new int[edtList.size()];
for(int i=0; i < edtList.size(); i++){
    id[i] = edtList.get(i).getId();
}
```

I hope that's helps you!

Thank You.